# Axios and reactjs showing empty posted data at php backend

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

Iam using the Axio Reactjs code below to post form data to php backend.

when I check **record.php** files from the chrome browser **console** and
**network**. it shows that connection is okay but posted data is empty.  it seems like the axios is not sending the data to php backend.

I have tried some solutions here on SO but cannot get it to work. Any work around will be appreciated.

```
axios({
  method:'POST',
  url:'http://localhost/mydata/record.php',
  rec:{
    myParameter1: 'test',
    myParameter2: 'test2',

  }

}).then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        this.setState({ data });
        console.log(data);
      })
.catch(err => { // log request error
        //this.setState({ error: false });
        console.error(err); 
      })
```

**php code**

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

//header("Content-Type: application/json");


//check if file_get_contents is enabled
if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
echo "enabled";
} else{
echo "not enabled";
}

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($data);

print_r($request);
print_r($data);


?>
```

Comment: Try to wrap the `rec` object inside `data` key, like `data : {rec: {...}}` [Docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In axios docs you can find data tag:

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

```
// `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
  // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
  // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
  // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
  // - Node only: Stream, Buffer
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred'
  },

  // syntax alternative to send data into the body
  // method post
  // only the value is sent, not the key
  data: 'Country=Brasil&City=Belo Horizonte',
```

this is what you need, there is no `rec` property in axios config

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the key `rec` in your data segment in axios or better still do something along the lines of

```
{
 rec: {
   myParameter1: 'test',
   myParameter2: 'test2',
 }
}
```